# Conjugation in $S_4$: orbit and stabilizers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Good morning all.

By operating $S_4$ on itself by conjugation, what will be its orbits and stabilizers?

Here is what I tried to do: I listed the $24$ elements of $S_4$ but I think that combining the elements between them would be a bit long. I need directions

Comment: Conjugation preserves cycle structure

Comment: It's the evening where I am.

Comment: Be a little more explicit

Comment: You have to be more explicit, Marc. What exactly don't you understand about "Conjugation preserves cycle structure"?

Comment: Do you have mental picture of what an orbit is? Of what conjugation does? Try doing it for $S_3$ to build intuition.

Comment: Okay . Since S4 qgit on itself by conjugation then the orbit of an element x of S4 is found by the expression g.x = gxg ^ (- 1) with g € S4. So since there are 24 elements to combine so I think it's long. So I would like to know if we can generalize. Sorry I do not master Latex writing well

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice general formula for conjugation in $S_n$, which is
$$
\sigma \: (a_1 \cdots a_k)(b_1 \cdots b_l) \cdots \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1) \cdots \sigma(a_k))(\sigma(b_1) \cdots \sigma(b_l)) \cdots,
$$
assuming the cycles between $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are all disjoint. This means that we can compute conjugates easily by considering the decomposition in disjoint cycles.

By the way, the proof of this formula is not very hard: you just show $\sigma(a_i)$ is mapped to $\sigma(a_{i+1})$, and similarly for $b_i$, and all other cycles in the cycle decomposition.

Comment: But in S4 there are 24 cycles that will have to be swapped one over the other. Wouldn't this method be long

Comment: Well, with a little bit more insight, not really. Since if the lengths of the cycles in the cycle decompositions of $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ are the same, then we can always find a permutation $\rho$ such that $\rho \sigma \rho^{-1} = \tau$, but if this is not true, we can't. For example, you can check $(12)(34)$ and $(13)(24)$ are conjugate by conjugating with $(2 3)$, but $(12)(34)$ and $(1234)$ are not conjugate.

Comment: Ok what would be the orbit of (123)

Comment: Any 3-cycle: for some 3-cycle $(a_1 a_2 a_3)$, consider a permutation $\sigma$ with $i \mapsto a_i$ (this is a bijection since $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are all different), then $\sigma (123) \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1) \sigma(2) \sigma(3)) = (a_1 a_2 a_3)$.

Comment: So if I understand properties since a1, a2, a3 are all different, the operation σ (123) σ − 1 = (σ (1) σ (2) σ (3)) = (a1a2a3) shows that the orbit of a n-cycle is a cycle of length n. And so to find the result of the orbit of (123) just look at all 3 cycles

Comment: Yes, and you can do the same for all other cycle types.

Comment: Ok for all Sverre. About the stabilizers how are we going to proceed.

Comment: You can use the formula. Start with just cycles: for what $\sigma \in S_n$ do we have $(a_1 \cdots a_n) = (\sigma(a_1) \cdots \sigma(a_n))$? Then generalise that to arbitrairy permutations.

Comment: Can you make an example please. Look at the example with the same (123). If I have to find a permutation such that g (1) = 2 and g (2) = 3 and g (3) = 1. So I think stabilizer of (123) would be itself for g € S4

Comment: Well, there are more that work, like $(123)^2 = (132)$. Remember the stabilisator is a subgroup and thus closed under multiplication. You can also use the orbit stabilizer theorem to compute the cardinality of the stabilizers.

Comment: Ok i see thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that cycle structure is preserved iff the permutations are conjugate.  See the first answer.

In $S_4$ the possible cycle structures are $(),(abcd),(abc), (ab)(cd)$ and $(ab)$, since there is also a theorem that any permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.

Now there are ${4\choose2}=6$ transpositions ($2$-cycles). $3$ products of two transpositions.  $4!/4=6 $ $4$-cycles.  And $8$ $3$-cycles.  And finally the identity forms its own orbit.

The class equation sums this up: 1+3+6+6+8.

Now you can get the orders of the stabilizers from the orbit-stabilizer theorem.  To get the actual stabilizers you may need to do it by hand.

Comment: You've listed four possible cycle structures, Chris, but of course there is a fifth, namely, $()$, the cycle structure of the identity element.

Comment: @Gerry of course you're right.  I allowed for it in the next two paragraphs, but left it out at the beginning.  Thanks for the input.