# Show that there is no permutation $\sigma$ in $S_4$ that satisfies $(1\,2\,3\,4) \circ \sigma = \sigma \circ (1\,2) (3\,4) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

My attempt is as below.

$(1\,2\,3\,4)=(1\,4)(1\,3)(1\,2)$ is an odd permutation.

$(1\,2)(3\,4)$ is an even permutation.

$\sigma$ can be either even or odd but not both.

Suppose $\sigma$  is even then $(1\,2\,3\,4) \circ \sigma$ is odd and $\sigma \circ (1\,2) (3\,4)$ is even. Which implies that $(1\,2\,3\,4) \circ \sigma \neq \sigma \circ (1\,2) (3\,4) $.

On the other hand suppose $\sigma$  is odd then
$(1\,2\,3\,4) \circ \sigma$ is even and $\sigma \circ (1\,2) (3\,4)$ is odd. Which again means that $(1\,2\,3\,4) \circ \sigma \neq \sigma \circ (1\,2) (3\,4) $.

Please let me know if this is the correct way to tackle the mentioned problem. Thanks

Comment: Your argument looks valid.  Another argument is that [conjugation preserves cycle structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48134/why-are-two-permutations-conjugate-iff-they-have-the-same-cycle-structure)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for letting me know. Also for the conjugation argument.

Comment: Look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3551859/403337

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument looks valid.  Whether $\sigma$ is even or odd, $\sigma^{-1}(1234)\sigma$ is odd, but $(12)(34)$ is even.

Another argument is that conjugation preserves cycle structure,

so we know that $\sigma^{-1} (1234) \sigma\ne(12)(34)$,

because $(1234)$ and $(12)(34)$ have different cycle structure.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another argument is that conjugation preserves the order of the element in question: $(1234)$ has order $4$, while $(12)(34)$ has order $2$.